# Create IMG using jQuery with Variable Position

Tags: jquery, variables, object, position

```
function hitQBlock(obj) {
  var objOne=$(obj),
    posOne = objOne.offset(),        
    posVert = posOne.top + (objOne.height()/2),
    posHoriz = posOne.left + (objOne.width()/2);
  var newCoin = document.createElement('.coin');
  newCoin.attr({
    style: 'position: absolute; top: posVert px; left: posHoriz px; width: 500px; height: 500px;', 
    src: 'http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/2297/super_mario/256/retro_coin.png'});
}
```

**First question:** How can I position the `newCoin` object to the position defined by the variables `posVert` and `posHoriz`? I attempted to use the `.val()` method, but it doesn't seem to work inside quotations

**Second question:** What is a better way to make new objects of a custom class inside of a function? My way, found above, does not work correctly.

Comment: close the string before adding the values....
`style: 'position: absolute; top: ' + posVert + 'px; left: ' + posHoriz + 'px; width: 500px; height: 500px;'`

Comment: Thank you, I should have thought of that xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

There was a typo on my code, I fixed it also here is a jsfiddle showing that it works. http://jsfiddle.net/p9n4X/

For better performance I would concat an html string and append it to the body something like this

```
var html = '<img class="coin" style="position: absolute; top: ' + posVert + 'px; left: '+ posHoriz +'px; width: 500px; height: 500px;" src="http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/2297/super_mario/256/retro_coin.png" />';

$('body').append(html);
```

Also notice I've followed Archer comment on closing the string.

Comment: Thank you so much! Feel free to help me with any of my other questions as well (: